# Sound notification in iOS 5.x in safari browser by js event (for eg. ajax response)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, ios

In iOS browser (safari) sounds that are triggered by events are blocked  (on ​​click - everything is OK)
Does anyone know a working solution - how it can be avoided?

Example: ajax chat message arrived and iphone \ ipad make a sound (the browser is open at the moment and active app)

thank you for your answers

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a media player that has a javascript API. Something like:-

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

This allows you to play files from javascript and it uses either html5 or flash so Safari wouldn't be able to block an event triggering it.

Answer (score 6):

The reason these events are blocked is to avoid any loading of data that is not user-initiated ([read Apple's explanation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)). That means you need to figure out a way to make the *user* trigger loading of the audio data. Make the user interact with the page before the meat of your app runs. The initialization could be triggered by something as simple as a `"touchstart"` fired on `document.body`, or a button that the user clicks to launch the app (example: have the user click a button that says "start chatting"). In that event's handler, load your audio file to a variable and make it available to the rest of your application. Then in your ajax success handler, play the sound:

HTML

```
<a id="initbutton">Initialize</a>
```

JS

```
var sound;
$('#initbutton').one('click',function(ev){
    sound = new Audio("http://soundjax.com/reddo/61767^ding.mp3"); 
    sound.load(); // load the audio data
    sound.volume=1; // make sure the volume is all the way up, though this doesn't work on iOS
});

$.ajax(...,function(data,status,jqxhr){ //presumably this will be triggered by some other code
    if(sound){
        sound.play()
    }
});
```

**[See the example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/SYQzh/)** Try initializing audio first, then start the ajax loop and vice versa. It will be silent until the audio is loaded.

This has been tested in iOS 5.1 on iPad 2 and iPhone 4S. I don't know if it will work on other devices or in older version of iOS.

I don't know of any other ways to make it work.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on a second generation iPod touch running iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to the accepted answer but I'm posting it in case others find it more readable/workable:

```
<script>

    //save the sound to play
    var sound=new Audio('sound.mp3');

    //start listening for a mousedown or touchstart event (the later needed for ios)
    $(window).bind('mousedown touchstart',function() {
        //turn down the volume
        sound.volume=0;
        //iOS needs muting set to true 
        sound.muted=true;
        //play the sound on mute
        sound.play();

        console.log("played sound on mute");

        //only need to do this once.  we can unbind these two events when done.
        //rework this if you have mousedown or touchstart bindings for other purposes
        $(window).unbind('mousedown');
        $(window).unbind('touchstart');
    });

    //play the sound after 10 seconds.
    //this is just to test to see if auto-playing works.
    //you'd actually be putting the inside parts of this into some other function
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        //make sure sound is back on
        sound.volume=1;
        sound.muted=false;
        //play the sound
        sound.play();
    },10000);

</script>
```